# Clojure - treat list elements as function parameters

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to do something similar to Python's `func(*lst)` but with Clojure, and without using the `apply` function. My admittedly silly use case is:

```
{:k1 v1 (cond exp '(:k2 v2) :else '(:k3 v3))}
```

So if exp was true, the dict would contain `{:k1 v1 :k2 v2}`, otherwise `{:k1 v1 :k3 v3}`. I basically want a Python-esque `*` applied to the return value of `cond`. I tried playing around with data/code modes with ', `, and ~, though didn't find a solution. I can repeat the `cond` for the individual parameters to the underlying `hash-map` but that kind of defeats the point.

Why? I just think it'd be cool if Clojure can do it easily. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. A single form can only be a single form: it cannot magically be two of them. If this were possible, all kinds of things would break.

In your particular example, the easy answer is

```
(apply hash-map :k1 v1 
                (cond exp   '(:k2 v2)
                      :else '(:k3 v3))
```

The only way to do this is apply, which turns a single **function parameter** into zero or more **function parameters**, by expanding them as a list. It cannot work at the source-code level for use in things like a hash literal.

Edit: I don't know much Python, but I'm pretty sure Python can't do this either. You can splat things into function calls, but not straight into source. You can't write

```
test_expr = ((x == 2), return x)
if *test_expr
```

or anything like it - it just isn't possible because the compiler has to analyze the `if` before it can understand what to do with `test_expr`. Likewise in Clojure, the compiler has to analyze the hash literal before it can understand what to do with the objects inside - it can't know that you "want" them expanded into the map expression somehow.

Comment: Thanks, I figured. Though the apply function isn't that ugly in the end I guess, I just like the curly brace form. A minor correction is that if v2 and v3 are variables it needs to be `\`(:k2 ~v2)`

Comment: If that's what you want, sure; I fixed your actual code, rather than interpret what I thought you probably meant. `\`(:k2 ~v2)` will work, but `[:k2 v2]` is much easier if that's what you want.